# How to insert multiple rows at once using INSERT INTO query

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, drupal-7

[image: The Base Table]

So Here is my problem,
      I want to insert a data from this table **(webform_submitted_data)** to anather table **(feedback_Analysis)** 
      The data I want to copy is the one with the *nid=20 and cid= 3,4,5*
      so the table will look like this,

[image: The feedback_analysis table]

so here is what I am doing,

```
 insert into feedback_analysis (service,type,feedback) 
        values ((select data from webform_submitted_data where nid=20 and cid=5),(select data from webform_submitted_data where nid=20 and cid=3),(select data from webform_submitted_data where nid=20 and cid=4));
```

but I'm getting an error 
      **ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row**

I got the reason behind that, the subquery is actually returning two rows in result which the single **INSERT INTO** query can not handle.

I want to insert **all the rows** in the table, so that I can process further

So please help me find the solution for this.

I actually want to apply a trigger which will directly insert values into **feedback_analysis table** once a new value of nid=20 is inserted into the table of **weform_submitted_data**

thank you.

Comment: You could specify the sid, and then it would return only one row.  Right now your specification is ambiguous.

Comment: There is NO need for this. mysql has `insert .. select from`. you don't need subqueries like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT 1`

```
insert into feedback_analysis (service,type,feedback) 
        values ((select data
                 from webform_submitted_data
                 where nid=20 and cid=5
                 limit 1),
                (select data
                 from webform_submitted_data
                 where nid=20 and cid=3
                 limit 1),
                (select data
                 from webform_submitted_data
                 where nid=20 and cid=4
                 limit 1));
```

Comment: With limit only one value is getting inserted into the table. I want to insert all the values with nid=20 and cid = 3,4,5 into that table.

Comment: @PratikDhole if `select data
                 from webform_submitted_data
                 where nid=20 and cid=4` returns more than one results, which one would you inserted as `feedback`? If you end up with more than one for cid 3 and 5 as well, how do you want them paired up into a single `feedback_analysis` record?

Comment: @Andreas see there are 4 columns in a table, when I select data having nid=20 and cid =4 then the results will be two values. 1) interactive session 2) Government provides......   I want them one below the other...so that when i perform my analysis algorithm it will be easy to analyze the sentiment of it......so that I will be able to visualize the Perticular service has perticuler amount of positive sentiments.....hope this will help